# How to get array from getPhotos() function to the callback function or how to get deep directory structure using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to gather the gallery folders and images that are listed on my server, but am having a difficult time getting the photos array to return with the results.  Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong that it won't send the data back?

My code:

```
    module.exports.getGalleryImages = function(req, res) {
  console.log('Fetch gallery image names');
  var gallerypath = './public/assets/gallery';
  function done(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(results);
    }
  }
  getGalleryFolders(gallerypath, done);
};

var getGalleryFolders = function(gallerypath, callback) {
  const galleryFolders = [];
  fs.readdir(gallerypath, async (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error: ', err);
      callback(err);
    }
    files.forEach(file => {
      let folder = { year: null, photos: [] };

      folder = { year: file, photos: [file.files] };
      galleryFolders.push(folder);
    });
    console.log(galleryFolders);
    callback(null, galleryFolders);
    // getPhotos(galleryFolders, gallerypath, callback);
  });
};

var getPhotos = function(galleryFolders, gallerypath, callback) {
  const gallery = [...galleryFolders];
  gallery.forEach(folder => {
    let subfolder = `${gallerypath}/${folder.year}`;
    fs.readdir(subfolder, (err, photos) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
        callback(err);
      }
      folder.photos = photos;
      console.log(
        `Returning folder ${folder.year} photos`,
        folder.photos.length
      );
      return folder;
      // console.log(folder);
    });
    gallery.push(folder);
    console.log('returning gallery', gallery);

    return gallery;
  });

  console.log(gallery);
  callback(null, gallery);
};
```

It gets the correct folders in the getGalleryFolders() function and passes them to the next function getPhotos().  The photos array is right, it just doesn't seem to want to leave that function no matter what or where I've moved return.

I'm getting a result of:

> [
>       {
>           "year": "2004",
>           "photos": [
>               null
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2011",
>           "photos": [
>               null
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2012",
>           "photos": [
>               null
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2013",
>           "photos": [
>               null
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2014",
>           "photos": [
>               null
>           ]
>       } ]

I want to return something like this:

> [
>       {
>           "year": "2004",
>           "photos": [
>               "1.jpg","3.jpg","somatic.jpg"
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2011",
>           "photos": [
>               "blue.jpg","green.jpg",yellow.jpg"
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2012",
>           "photos": [
>               "a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg"
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2013",
>           "photos": [
>               "2013.jpg"
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "year": "2014",
>           "photos": [
>               "2014.jpg"
>           ]
>       } ]

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` will get you the names of all the files in a directory. It does not get you the files.

You can see this when you create the objects in your array:

```
folder = { year: file, photos: [file.files] }
```

Where the property 'year' gets set to a string (2004, 2011, etc), which must be the names of the files in that directory. This is also why your photos array is always null. The string stored in the 'file' variable doesn't have any properties, because it's a string and not an object. When you try to access `file.files`, that 'files' property doesn't exist.

To get the contents of the files, you'll need to call something like `fs.readFile` with all the filenames you've gotten with readdir.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Comment: Ah, sorry that should have read photos: [] because I then wanted to run the getPhotos() function.  I've fixed it so it goes to the next function, but it's not executing it in the order expected.  I'm getting the gallery returned before the folder is updated with the photo list.  I'm guessing because fs.readdir must be async?  I don't know how to change it to be sync.

Comment: Oooooh!  I figured it out!  I needed to run fs.readdirSync() instead of fs.readdir when inside my foreach loop so it would wait for that to execute before returning the gallery.  It works!